# Attempting to forward select l3keys arguments from an outer environment to a tblr: "Unexpandable command inside column type"

Tags: latex3, tabularray, l3keys

I'm attempting to create an environment that takes its arguments as key-value pairs, uses some of them, and then forwards the rest on to a `tblr` environment from tabularray.

This results in an "Unexpandable command \l_foo_colspec_str inside column type" error for the colspec parameter, and while the style variable doesn't yield an error, neither does `hlines` get forwarded to `tblr`.

I'm reasonably certain that the issue is on the l3keys side rather than tabularray, since replacing the `tblr` with a `tabular` (and dropping the hlines bits) also fails (with an "Illegal pream-token" error).

I would like to *either*:

1. Pass specific arguments on to tblr individually
2. Remove specific key-value pairs from #1 and then do `\begin{tblr}{#1}`

(It can be made to work by passing the "outer" argument list and tblr argument list separately (`\begin{tbl}{colspec=llx,hlines}{foo=bar}`), but that's a less elegant interface.)

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { foo } {
    bar .tl_set:N = \l_foo_bar_str,
    colspec .tl_set:N = \l_foo_colspec_str,
    style .tl_set:N = \l_foo_style_clist,
}

\newenvironment{tbl}[1]
{
    \keys_set:nn{foo}{#1}
    \l_foo_bar_str
    \begin{tblr}{colspec=\l_foo_colspec_str,\l_foo_style_clist}%
}
{
    \end{tblr}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tbl}{
    bar=baz,
    colspec=llx,
    style={hlines},
}
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
\end{tbl}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tblr` is defined in terms of a `+b` argument type with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, also environments defined through it must comply. You also need to expand the argument before feeding it to `\begin{tblr}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { foo } {
    bar .tl_set:N = \l_foo_bar_tl,
    colspec .tl_set:N = \l_foo_colspec_tl,
    style .tl_set:N = \l_foo_style_clist,
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tbl}{m +b}
{
    \keys_set:nn{foo}{#1}
    \l_foo_bar_tl
    \exp_args:Nne \begin{tblr}{colspec=\l_foo_colspec_tl,\l_foo_style_clist}
    #2
    \end{tblr}
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tbl}{
    bar=baz,
    colspec=llX,
    style={hlines},
}
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
a & b & c \\
\end{tbl}

\end{document}
```

Please, use `tl` and not `str` for token list variables.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried the +b before, but exp_args was the major piece I was missing completely.  A couple of followup questions: Is `tl` vs `str` syntactically significant, or just a naming convention? (I'll do the right thing either way, but I want to understand why.)  And for the `l_foo_style_clist` argument, if I pass a somewhat more complicated argument than in the MWE, `style={hlines,row{odd}={font=\large}}`, it gives a TeX capacity exceeded. Tossing a `\noexpand` in front of `\large` makes it work, but is there any way to declare the argument (or the environment) s.t. that's unnecessary?